# search a single word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

below i mentioned my search page coding. its working fine. but i have a small problem. for example if users selects Guest Name from combobox and then type the query name (for example i stored Rahul Dravid in my mysql db) in input text box. if they enters "rahul dravid" in the input textfield its show the result correctly. but if they enters "dravid" or "rahul" in the input textfield it does not show the results. how to search a single word in mysql?

```
 <form action="searchdetail.php" method="post"> 
      SEARCH BY:
        <select name="searchby">
        <option value="gname">Guest Name</option>
        <option value="gphone">Guest Phone</option>
        </select>
        <input name="query" type="text" />
        <input name="subval" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
```

and then

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['subval']))
        { 
            $query = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['query']));   
            $field = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchby']));

            $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE `$field` = '$query'"); 
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th width=120>Guest Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Guest Phone</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['gname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['gphone'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE `$field` LIKE '%$query%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html):

```
SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE `$field` LIKE '%$query%'
```

This will return any results that have your query in them.

**Example:**

> Record: rahul dravid
>
> rahu
>
> drav
>
> dravid
>
> rahul
>
> rahul
>
> drav

All will return your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE `$field` LIKE '%$query%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

just write your query line like that:

```
$sql = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE `$field` LIKE '%$query%' ");
```